# Python Multiprocess OpenCV Webcam & Get Request

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing but have spent a whole day trying to get the following to work properly.

I'm trying to run my Webcam using OpenCV (func_run_forever) in parallel with a single requests.get (func_run_once).
So the expected result is my webcam running in a window (imshow), and a single Response 200 from requests.get while my webcam is running.
However, the request.get won't run until I quit the OpenCV window.

Any help, tips, clues...or even answers would be much appreciated!

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import cv2
import requests

def func_run_forever():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def func_run_once():
    res = requests.get('https://www.google.com.au')
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func_run_forever())
    p2 = Process(target=func_run_once())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: I think you meant to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing.

Comment: @TinNguyen tried that too and still got the same results.
I imported **threading** instead of multiprocessing, and updated p1=threading.Thread... instead of p1=Process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, your code needs like 1% modification to work as intended. Change this:

```
p1 = Process(target=func_run_forever())
p2 = Process(target=func_run_once())
```

to this:

```
p1 = Process(target=func_run_forever)
p2 = Process(target=func_run_once)
```